# Is there any graphics library in a higher level than OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, graphics

I am looking for a graphics library for 3D reconstruction research to develop my specific viewer based on some library. OpenGL seems in a low level and I have to remake the wheel everywhere. And I also tried VTK(visualization toolkit). However, it seems too abstract that I need to master many conceptions before I start. Is there any other graphics library? I prefer to program in python. So I would like the library has a python wrapper. I think something like O3D would be better. But O3D is for javascript and it seems that Google already stops the development.

Comment: Any opinions on the various python graphic libraries that have been developed?  What requirements are you looking for?

Comment: @James Black, I only tried PyOpenGL and Python-VTK. The former is just a simple wrapper of COpenGL, and the latter is over-complicated. I am looking for a library that is lightweight and object-oriented.

Comment: Did you combine PyOpenGL with NumPy and/or SciPy? A lot of maths are already done there, and what sort of tools are you looking at avoiding the wheel re-invention?

Comment: @Xavier Ho:It seems very difficult to identify what sort of tools required. I just feel that PyOpenGL makes me consider a lot of low level detail which is annoying.

Comment: It is. Eventually you'll have to keep to reuse the old code that wraps PyOpenGL, otherwise you should probably look at PyProcessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) with [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/)? The two goes very well together. Wheaties' suggest is quite good as well, although [PyOgre](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/PyOgre) also has a steep learning curve, as it is indeed higher-level. On another thought, there is also [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/), which is a Python wrapper of [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/).

I personally prefer PyOpenGL, and you can use [WxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) or [PyQT](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) to create your rendering context.

Also, there is [PyProcessing](http://code.google.com/p/pyprocessing/), which is still in early stages, but very, very nifty.

Comment: I have skimmed pyglet and it is really powerful.

Answer (score 2):

[Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org/) seems to be a nice 3D graphics library designed to be used in Python, although it's mostly game oriented. I've browsed the manuals a few times and it's very polished and of a high quality, it has even been used in some big studio's games (like Disney's Pirates of the Caribbean online, if I remember well).

Answer (score 0):

You could try mlab / Mayavi (a wrapper for VTK). There's some examples here: http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/mlab.html

Comment: Is it very documented? A big problem of VTK is the lack of good tutor and only have C++ documentation.

Comment: The documentation looks OK. I haven't actually used mlab, but I was looking at it a while ago. The function you are likely to be looking for is "triangular mesh", which is here: http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#enthought.mayavi.mlab.triangular_mesh

Answer (score -1):

I have no personal experience with this, but I have heard some decent things about [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

I used openGL with C++ a few years back - found it quite low level. I also have used Java3D which seemed to be a bit higher level. If you are not stuck on using python - try Java3D - very simple to get up and running.